# Evaluate RHS of perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, eval

I'm trying to learn how to evaluate (i.e. perform actual mathematical calculations) in regex replacements.

I've got a file `test.txt` which contains:

```
|R 1:27_2-6-02
I 1656 misc:IN 1 2200 1470 0 1 '
C 1655 2 1 0C 1659 2 2 0
```

From the command line (in Windows) I'm running the following:

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s!(I.*?)(misc:IN 1 )(\d+)(.*?')!${1}misc:OUT 2 ${3}/10${4}!e" test.txt
```

I'm expecting the result to have "misc:IN 1 " replaced by "misc:OUT 2 " **and** for it to be followed by 220, not 2200. However, this is not working.

I've looked at the tutorial [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), which shows the following example where there is a mathematical calculation performed during the regex substition:

```
# convert percentage to decimal
$x = "A 39% hit rate";
$x =~ s!(\d+)%!$1/100!e; # $x contains "A 0.39 hit rate"
```

Comment: Always use warnings. Even in one-liners you can use `perl -w`. If you had, you would have gotten `Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "${1}misc"` and several other clues to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! While messing around with different variations on my code, some of my more erroneous attempts were actually spitting out complaints like the ones you've shown but I'm a bit of a Perl noob so they weren't very illuminating to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RHS must be fully valid perl code to be evalled.  You need to define and concatenate strings.

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s!(I.*?)(misc:IN 1 )(\d+)(.*?')!qq{${1}misc:OUT 2 } . ${3}/10 . qq{${4}}!e" test.txt
```

Also note the use of `qq{}` for strings since `""` is used on the command line to enclose the perl code.

Comment: That appears to be doing the job! I suspected I was being too lax with my RHS code but I wasn't sure where to go. Thanks! I will accept this as the answer as soon as I can (apparently it's too soon currently).